# Why won't my input search tag display in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm going to display a search box on my Vue website, but it won't display.

My code is (this in body.vue):

```
<template>
  <div class="searching">
     <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search.." /> 
  </div>
</template>
```

I put it in the data()

```
export default {
name: "body",
data() {
  return {
    search: '',
```

My App.vue looks like this:

```
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <header id="header"></header>
     <router-view id="routeView"></router-view>
   </div>
 </template>
```

The data() return also contain other stuff. Why can I see my searching box?

Comment: can you post full code or at least part of how this component is integrated with rest of the Vue app?

Comment: @niklaz my body.vue just contains other templates

Comment: Is the first template the header template ? If not, are you sure the current route is correct ?

Comment: In body.vue i dont have any header. I do have a own header.vue. I am new to vue, do i need a header tag in body.vue too? @Seblor

Comment: Your App.vue file has `<header id="header"></header>` so there should be no issue displaying the input from the first template if it is the template of the header component. However, if the first template is supposed to be displayed with the routeur, you need to make sure the current route is the correct one (defined in the router settings)

Comment: @Seblor ok, i moved my code to the header.vue(that contains the header tag) and now it display. But, now it display on all of my pages, i want it only to display in on my bode.vue page. How do i do that?

Comment: You should take a look at some tutorials. Of course the input will be displayed in all your pages since it's in the same template as the router.

Comment: @celllaa95 Just move `<header />` from `App.vue` to `body.vue`